# PHP JsonReader not found

Tags: php, composer

Мне нужно работать с большим json файлом, и для этого собираюсь использовать [JsonReader](https://github.com/pcrov/JsonReader)

Я ввел в консоль `composer init`, `composer require pcrov/jsonreader`
Создалась папка vendor - вроде как установился

Было пару ошибок по типу нет ext-intl, но я включил его в конфиге и reader установился.

В `index.php` такой код

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use pcrov\jsonreader\JsonReader;

$reader = new JsonReader();
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'pcrov\jsonreader\Exception' not found in W:\domains\VK-hacking-attempt\index.php:5 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in W:\domains\VK-hacking-attempt\index.php on line 5

Почему php не видит `JsonReader`?
При этом я пробовал в phpstorm смотреть, что он автокомплитом предлагает в `use pcrov\jsonreader\`

Comment: Подключаешь ты Exception а создать пытаешься JsonReader. В чём прикол?

Comment: ну и да:  подключение-то вендора где? https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading

Comment: ахах, да, это я тестил, может Extention будет работать, забыл обратно поменять, но не суть

Comment: Действительно, забыл про него, видимо нужно мне php подучить, я всё же больше по js

Comment: Но это не помогло, я обновил код. прописал `composer dump-autoload` - но все равно `class not found`

Comment: `use pcrov\JsonReader\JsonReader;`?

Comment: Мда, мне стыдно. Но в любом случае спасибо)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Заменит

```
use pcrov\jsonreader\JsonReader;
```

на

```
use pcrov\JsonReader\JsonReader;
```